# JQuery UI combobox event when cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm using JQuery UI combobox and I was searching for a way to perform some actions when the selected value changes. I found this solution in StackOverflow:

```
$("#comboboxname").combobox({ 
    select: function (event, ui) { 
        // CODE
    } 
});
```

It works only when I select a correct value from the list, but it does not trigger when I select the text from the combobox and delete it (that is, when I deselect everything).

Is there another way to catch such event? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

JQuery UI combobox is just a wrapper for a normal html `<select>` control. So the select callback can only fire when an actual `<option>` is selected.

Maybe you can try another combobox plugin like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). It is somewhat more flexible than the JQuery UI combobox plugin.

Answer (score 1):

select2 provides intercepting the select2-removed event:

```
$("#myCombo").select2({
    placeholder: "Select Something",
    allowClear: true,
});
$("#myCombo")
    .on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
        log("selecting val=" + e.val + " choice=" + JSON.stringify(e.choice));
    })
    .on("select2-removed",   function(e) {
        log("removed");
    });
```